# window.location is a correct method to redirect to the external web in React?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to redirect to an external page in a react app.
After searching a lot of blogs, I come with the following code.
However, not working at all and no error, no warning. Which piece do I miss?

```
class test extends Component{
    constructor() {
       super()
       this.state = {
           redirect : false;
       }
    }
    // here is some logic will trigger the redirect as true
    render( 
        if(this.state.redirect) {
           <Route path='/search' component={() => { window.location = 'https://www.google.com'; return null;} }/>
        }
        return (
            //other render if the redirect is false
        )
    )
}
```

Comment: It's window.location.href not window.location

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The route is not being loaded to the dom. Only things inside of the return will load to the dom. If the route is loaded on the page with the with that path you will be redirected to google. I would suggest removing the Route tag and just use the window.location. Your render method is also formatted oddly I recommend changing it to this

```
class test extends Component{
    state={
        redirect:true
    }
    render(){
        if(this.state.redirect) {
            window.location = 'https://www.google.com'
        }
        return(
        <h1>I didn't redirect</h1>
        )
    } 
}
```

Or if you are just wanting to render only while the user is also on path "/search" and the redirect case is true you can try this instead:

```
class test extends Component{
    state={
        redirect:true
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <>
                <h1>Normal Page Stuff</h1>
                {this.state.redirect ? <Route path='/google/search' component={() => { window.location = 'https://www.google.com'; return null;} }/> : null }
            </>
        )
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Easy than my image